# Inherited selection field isn't selecting in odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15

I've inherited the res.partner model and added 2 selection value in company_type field as like below

```
class InheritContract(models.Model):
_inherit = "res.partner"

company_type = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('vendor', 'Vendor'),('panel', 'Panel')])
```

These two selection value is showing but I can not select them. Does anyone have any solution?
[problem in the video link](https://youtu.be/53ut0d8KrQE)

Answer (score 1):

`company_type` is computed so you should also change the related methods, for example the compute method:

```py
    @api.depends('is_company')
    def _compute_company_type(self):
        for partner in self:
            partner.company_type = 'company' if partner.is_company else 'person'
```

You also can see that there is a relation between the fields `company_type` and `is_company`. More you have to take care of.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. If anyone want to add more Contacts Type in Odoo Contact(res.partner). Here is the code

```
class InheritContract(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    is_vendor = fields.Boolean(string='Is a Vendor', default=False,
                               help="Check if the contact is a Vendor, otherwise it is a person/company")
    is_panel = fields.Boolean(string='Is a Panel', default=False,
                              help="Check if the contact is a Panel, otherwise it is a person/company/vendor")

    company_type = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('vendor', 'Vendor'),('panel', 'Panel')],
                                    compute='_compute_company_type',inverse='_write_company_type')

    @api.depends('is_company')
    def _compute_company_type(self):
        for partner in self:
            if partner.is_company:
                partner.company_type = 'company'
            elif partner.is_vendor:
                partner.company_type = 'vendor'
            elif partner.is_panel:
                partner.company_type = 'panel'
            else:
                partner.company_type = 'person'

    def _write_company_type(self):
        for partner in self:
            if partner.company_type == 'panel':
                partner.is_panel = True
                partner.is_company = False
                partner.is_vendor = False
            elif partner.company_type == 'vendor':
                partner.is_vendor = True
                partner.is_panel = False
                partner.is_company = False
            elif partner.company_type == 'company':
                partner.is_company = True
                partner.is_vendor = False
                partner.is_panel = False
            else:
                partner.is_company = False
                partner.is_vendor = False
                partner.is_panel = False

    @api.onchange('company_type')
    def onchange_company_type(self):
        if self.company_type == 'panel':
            self.is_panel = True
            self.is_vendor = False
            self.is_company = False
        elif self.company_type == 'vendor':
            self.is_vendor = True
            self.is_panel = False
            self.is_company = False
        elif self.company_type == 'company':
            self.is_company = True
            self.is_vendor = False
            self.is_panel = False
        else:
            self.is_company = False
            self.is_vendor = False
            self.is_panel = False
```

Hope this will work fine so far.